# Box-shadow covered by content?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a box shadow on it which looks great. The problem I am having is that when I add content to the div the content will cover the shadow. How to I have the box-shadow on my div and have it on top of any child content of that div?

This is the css set on the containing div

```
    #hero_graphic {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 10px #333;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
```

This inset box-shadow will show if no content is inside the div but is covered when I add content to the div.

Comment: shadow on top of content !!! did you mean overlay ?

Comment: show some code or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) it

Comment: I tried this and it`s really problematic. I guess the only solution is to apply the shadow directly to the div and not the the wrapper. Or try with the relative position to the wrapper and absolute the the hero_graphic...

Comment: maybe no need for inset // see this [tuto](http://www.alsacreations.com/tuto/lire/910-creer-des-ombrages-ombres-css-box-shadow-text-shadow.html) -in french but useful-

Answer (score 0):

You want to tell the content to behave and keep its distance from the shadow be setting the `padding` of `#hero_graphic` to about 15 pixels.

[See example](http://jsfiddle.net/n8c94/2/)